# Is it possible to have multiple entities with same simple name used by spring data jpa repositories?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Have two entities with same simple names in different packages, referenced to same table name but different schemes (physically different tables). Code compiles with no errors. Executes correctly if the behavior with these tables was not triggered. But error `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property description` occurs when there is a call to repository with data for home.

**Questions:**

- where is the case described in the documentation?
- is there a workaround which will exclude renaming of entity classes?

First entity: package home, table is under default schema (specified in entity manager):

```
package com.example.domain.home;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String description;
}
```

Second entity: package work, same simple name, same table name, but different schema:

```
package com.example.domain.work;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DATA", schema = "WORK")
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    public String id;
}
```

Repository to find data from home:

```
package com.example.domain.home;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {
    Data findTopByDescription(String description);
}
```

Repository to find data from work, need to specify name, otherwise spring don't want to autowire correctly:

```
package com.example.domain.work;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("workDataRepository")
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {
}
```

Consume one of the repository:

```
package com.example.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.domain.home.DataRepository;

@Service
public class HomeService {

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    public void test(){
        dataRepository.findTopByDescription("Test");
    }
}
```

Have not found any related information in spring data nor hibernate documentation.
If there is any other information that will be useful, please, leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three relevant name-like values for an entity class:

- the fully qualified class name: You are fine on this one since it includes the package name.
- the table name: You are fine again since the schema makes them distinct.
- the entity name: That one is used in JPQL queries and (I guess) in Maps internally to hold metadata. This is by default the same as the simple class name. But you can change it using the [`@Entity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) annotation to (almost) whatever you like.

Comment: do you have a reference for the last one? I assume spring repository is using JPQL.

Comment: @uli Except for the guess, it's coming from the linked JavaDoc. For derived queries Spring Data uses the Criteria API: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java